# How to map workflow task to the originating workflow

Tags: workflow, development, event-handlers

I would like to fire an event when Workflow Task is completed and I would like to check the original item and workflow that created the task. But I cannot find any value among the Workflow task properties that would point to the originating list, list item and workflow instance. Is this possible?

I am using OOTB Approval workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, there is [SPWorkflowTask.WorkflowId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowtask.workflowid.aspx) Property available.